# Getting Google Spradsheet data in JSON format

Tags: json, http, google-sheets

I am trying to get a google spreadsheet content in JSON but id doesnt seem to be working using the following way.
I am sending an HTTP request using the following URL. You can just copy that to URL to see the result.

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Sp18_fOs8SSP_fwB54lv7IoL42uDaioZM1LTRD4rL8o/od6/public/values?alt=json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="results"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript">


 // ID of the Google Spreadsheet
 var spreadsheetID = "1Sp18_fOs8SSP_fwB54lv7IoL42uDaioZM1LTRD4rL8o";

 // Make sure it is public or set to Anyone with link can view 
 var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID + "/od6/public/values?alt=json";

 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

  var entry = data.feed.entry;


  $(entry).each(function(){
     for (var prop in this){alert(this[prop]);}
    // Column names are name, age, etc.
    $('.results').prepend('<h2>'+this.gsx$name.$t+'</h2><p>'+this.gsx$age.$t+'</p>');
  });

 });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```